# How can we redirect to the address that we gave to the IE when we open a particular site?

Tags: html, browser

my question is how can we redirect to another address that we already gave it to IE when we go to a particular address? can we use parental guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use php to redirect them if this is a site you built.

```
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.website.com");
?>
```